# Copy range to last blank line

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with three sheets with ten columns (A through J).
Sheet1 is a data entry sheet that uses VBA code to transfer a record to the next blank line in Sheet2 where each data entry row is stored. This is working.
Sheet3 is an EDIT sheet to modify a previously-entered record on sheet2.

Using the EDIT sheet, I have VBA code that looks for the matching claim number on sheet2 and clears out the comments.

PROBLEM:
The next time there is a record with comments transferred to sheet2 using the ".End(xlUp)" method it puts that comment on J2 vs. J10 because J1-9 were empty.

QUESTION:
How can I put the comment for claim #10 on J10?

As a workaround I put a dash on each empty line where there are no comments, but that is not an optimal solution as there are many hands that touch that workbook.

Comment: You're right about your work-around: it is simply bad design, you should clear the comments when you don't need them. Why are you working out the last row from column J? You know for example that column A is not empty, therefore, `lastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` and then `Sheet2.Cells(lastRow, "J") = theNewComment`

Comment: I think using comments is a bad idea. You shouldn't be working around that decision. Instead just amend the design for the row to have another column, name it Comments, and then your table can share the data with other lookups, etc. Comment designs in formulas and code is going to give you a headache. I once had to redo an entire workbook of comments and i made a function that looped through each, and deciphered a date from it... then stored the comment in a row / cell in the table, then deleted the comment. You can make that fairly easily and it can be used on existing ranges with comments

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2 decide on a column that you know will always have a value (Column A for example). Work out the last row number using that column

```
lastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

And then use `lastRow` to update the new comment

```
Sheet2.Cells(lastRow, "J") = theNewComment
```